# how to insert row matrix to another matrix in python with decimal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I have a matrix for example:

```
mat = np.array([
    [80, -20, -20, 20],
    [-20, 40, -20, 20],
    [-20, -20, 130, 20]
])
```

row , for example:

```
[  0.             0.           107.1428571429  42.8571428571]
```

I want to insert this row to third row matrix for example:
I expect my output:

```
[80, -20, -20, 20]
[-20, 40, -20, 20]
[0, 0, 107.1428571429,42.8571428571]
```

but my output:

```
[80, -20, -20, 20]
[-20, 40, -20, 20]
[0, 0, 107,42]
```

without decimal

Comment: Can you share your code so that we can look for errors?

Comment: Presumably `mat` has integer type and the values are converted to integers when inserting them.

Comment: mat = np.array([
    [80, -20, -20, 20],
    [-20, 40, -20, 20],
    [-20, -20, 130, 20]
])
zz=np.array([  0,             0,           107.1428571429,  42.8571428571])
mat[2,:] = zz
print mat

Comment: From docs *In place operations will perform the calculation using the precision decided by the data type of the two operands, but will silently downcast the result (if necessary) so it can fit back into the array. Therefore, for mixed precision calculations, `A {op}= B` can be different than `A = A {op} B`.*

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of the elements to not be `int` but e.g. `float64`

```
mat = mat.astype('float64')
```